# how to "revoke" a "GRANT OPTION" from an mysql user/database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, linux

i have a mysql installation with lots of users and grants. But one grant is unique, since its supposed to be a simple DB user and usually does not need GRANT privileges. However someone added it when the account where added. It looks like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'freg2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*XXXXX';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, \
    REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, \
    LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, \
    CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE \
    ON `freg2`.* TO 'freg2'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I searched the net (and this site) for a solution on how to remove that "GRANT OPTION" thingy, without recreating the whole grant/account . so far without luck.

Is there really no way just to remove "this" privilege or right from that account ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as usual...

```
root@localhost:playground > grant select, grant option on playground.* to asdf@localhost identified by 'asdf';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

root@localhost:playground > show grants for asdf@localhost;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for asdf@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'asdf'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7F0C90A004C46C64A0EB9DDDCE5DE0DC437A635C' |
| GRANT SELECT ON `playground`.* TO 'asdf'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > revoke grant option on playground.* from asdf@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:playground > show grants for asdf@localhost;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for asdf@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'asdf'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7F0C90A004C46C64A0EB9DDDCE5DE0DC437A635C' |
| GRANT SELECT ON `playground`.* TO 'asdf'@'localhost'                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) is also as always very helpful.

Comment: Except the "usual" may not be equally obvious to everyone, as evidenced by [this old bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27288). Still, good job both showing how it's done and illustrating how it works.

Comment: thanks! after all my failed attempts and net searching i am surprised that what i already tried multiple times and failed, now is supposed to work. i guess the problem was some nasty details with syntax and quoting that i did wrong. what worked for me at the end was: 
    `mysql -u"${targetMySqlUser}" -p"${targetMySqlPass}" -e "revoke grant option on freg2.* from freg2@%;"` - btw: i read the manual for 5.5 (revoke) , but without a proper example i still had trouble putting something together that worked.